# How to open Windows Settings Pages from code in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, operating-system

How do I open Windows settings like the ones below from code in C#? I'm not trying to manipulate them, but to just open them for the user.

Sorry, I don't even know the right keywords for this question.

[image]

[image]

*(Screenshots are in German.)*

**Edit:** (in addition to the answers)

- Search in `C:\Windows\System32\` for `*.cpl` or `*.msc`. A few interesting ones:

  - firewall.cpl
  - hdwwiz.cpl

Comment: Hope this answer help you --: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/552096/413736

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open both via:

```
Process.Start("ncpa.cpl");
Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"shell:::{BB06C0E4-D293-4f75-8A90-CB05B6477EEE}");
```

Answer (score 4):

try this to run Network-Adapter-Settings

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("NCPA.cpl");
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Sorry, I take that back. It works just as well. Even better without me having to use a path to an exe.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use;

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("NCPA.cpl");
```